# Given a function object, how do I find its name and module?

Tags: julia

Given a function object `f`, how do I find:

1. Function's **name**.
2. **Module**(s) of its method(s)?

In Julia 0.4 I was able to find name using `f.env.name`, but no tips for module. For Julia 0.5 I wasn't able to find any of two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@oxinabox's answer is correct. To add, `typeof(f).name.mt.name` is the v0.5 replacement for `f.env.name`. That can be useful to avoid the `.` that occurs when just applying `string` to a function introduced in a non-stdlib module. There also exists `Base.function_name(f)` which is probably less likely to break when the Julia version changes.

To get the module that a function (type) is introduced in, rather than the modules of individual methods, there's `typeof(f).name.module`, or the probably-better version, `Base.function_module(f)`. The module of the method table is probably the same; that can be obtained through `typeof(f).name.mt.module`.

Note that `f.env` in v0.4 is a direct equivalent of `typeof(f).name.mt`, so on v0.4 the same `f.env.name` and `f.env.module` apply.

Comment: `Base.function_name(f)` and `Base.function_module(f)` look like a perfect solution for Julia 0.5. Maybe you also have a solution for module name in Julia 0.4?

Comment: @ffriend Sure, added an additional paragraph.

Comment: Ah, didn't get it first. Thanks!

Comment: `Base.function_name` and `Base.function_module` are not there in Julia 1.0 anymore.

Comment: In Julia 1.0 the new function is `Base.nameof` https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.nameof-Tuple{Function}

Answer (score 11):

Name is easy: `Symbol(f)` or `string(f)` if you want a string

Module is, as you know going to be per method (i.e per type signature).
`methods(f)` with return a method table that prints out all the methods and where they are, in terms of files.

You can do `[meth.module for meth in methods(f)]` to get there modules

So to use an example, the `collect` function.

```
julia> using DataStructures #so we have some non-Base definitions

julia> Symbol(collect)
:collect

julia> methods(collect)
# 5 methods for generic function "collect":
collect(r::Range) at range.jl:813
collect{T}(::Type{T}, itr) at array.jl:211
collect(itr::Base.Generator) at array.jl:265
collect{T}(q::DataStructures.Deque{T}) at /home/ubuntu/.julia/v0.5/DataStructures/src/deque.jl:170
collect(itr) at array.jl:236

julia> [meth.module for meth in methods(collect)]
5-element Array{Module,1}:
 Base
 Base
 Base
 DataStructures
 Base

julia> first(methods(collect, (Deque,))).module
 DataStructures
```

Comment: Looks good, thanks! Is there a way to find method's module in Julia 0.4 as well?

Comment: @ffriend The solution presented here works exactly the same as v0.4.

Answer (score 7):

In `Julia 1.x` the commands are:

1. [`Base.nameof`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.nameof-Tuple%7BFunction%7D)
2. [`Base.parentmodule`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.parentmodule)

Since this two methods are exported, also `nameof` and `parentmodule` works.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer but closely related: you can find the file name and line number of `f` using `functionloc(f)`